# Redshift could avoid full table scan using sortkey and joined table

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a very large table "event" in Redshift and a much smaller table "d_date" representing dates. Redshift will run a full table scan on "event" for the SQL below unless I uncomment the commented part. Table event has date_id as its sort key.

Why doesn't Redshift figure out it's much cheaper to first scan d_date and then restrict event table scan by matching values?

```
select d_date.date_id, count(*)
from d_date
join event on d_date.date_id = event.date_id
where d_date.sqldate > '2016-06-03'
/* without this the query will do a full table scan and run very slow */
/* and d_date.date_id > 20160603 */
group by 1;
```

This is EXPLAIN output:

```
QUERY PLAN
XN HashAggregate  (cost=19673968.12..19673971.77 rows=1460 width=4)
->  XN Hash Join DS_DIST_ALL_NONE  (cost=78.63..18758349.28 rows=183123769 width=4)
    Hash Cond: ("outer".date_id = "inner".date_id)
    ->  XN Seq Scan on event  (cost=0.00..7523125.76 rows=752312576 width=4)
    ->  XN Hash  (cost=74.98..74.98 rows=1460 width=4)
          ->  XN Seq Scan on d_date  (cost=0.00..74.98 rows=1460 width=4)
                Filter: (sqldate > '2016-06-03'::date)
```

With the part uncommented the table phase will look like this instead:

```
    ->  XN Seq Scan on event  (cost=0.00..928.32 rows=74266 width=4)
```

I have VACUUMed and ANALYZEd both tables and I have primary and foreign keys set up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Amazon Redshift documentation specifically addresses this topic in [Amazon Redshift Best Practices for Designing Queries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_designing-queries-best-practices.html):

> If possible, use a WHERE clause based on the primary sort column of the largest table in the query to restrict the dataset. The query planner can then use row order to help determine which records match the criteria, so it can skip scanning large numbers of disk blocks. Without this, the query execution engine must scan the entire table.
>
> Add predicates to filter tables that participate in joins, even if the predicates apply the same filters. The query returns the same result set, but Amazon Redshift is able to filter the join tables before the scan step and can then efficiently skip scanning blocks from those tables.
>
> For example, suppose you want to join `SALES` and `LISTING` to find ticket sales for tickets listed after December, grouped by seller. Both tables are sorted by date. The following query joins the tables on their common key and filters for `listing.listtime` values greater than December 1:

```
select listing.sellerid, sum(sales.qtysold)
from sales, listing
where sales.salesid = listing.listid
and listing.listtime > '2008-12-01'
group by 1 order by 1;
```

> The WHERE clause doesn't include a predicate for `sales.saletime`, so the execution engine is forced to scan the entire `SALES` table. If you know the filter would result in fewer rows participating in the join, then add that filter as well. The following example cuts execution time significantly:

```
select listing.sellerid, sum(sales.qtysold)
from sales, listing
where sales.salesid = listing.listid
and listing.listtime > '2008-12-01'
and sales.saletime > '2008-12-01'
group by 1 order by 1;
```